# How to create a Mac OS X Yosemite dmg bootable Installer Version?

Tags: macos, install, dmg

I have a Mac OS X Yosemite downloaded file like this:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Like I see, it must have a Yosemite.app file in it, so why doesn't this have the file? This is truly from an [Official Apple Website](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/48498/os-x-yosemite). It just has a .pkg file. Can anybody explain this to me? And, How to create a complete bootable Yosemite 10.10.5 DMG disk image for clean OS install?

Comment: Is this an update? If so, you should know that you can not install any OS X version from an update. Also, as far as I know, you can not currently get Yosemite from the Apple store.

Comment: it is from http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/48498/os-x-yosemite.

Comment: The file you downloaded is to small to be any complete version of Yosemite. Your file size is comparable to the file you can download from [OS X Yosemite 10.10.5 Update](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1833?locale=en_US). This file is named `osxupd10.10.5.dmg` and is 995 MB in size. It is an update from OS X 10.10.4 to OS X 10.10.5.

Comment: Can you not go to the Apple Store and get El Capitan OS X 10.11?

Answer (score 1):

It's inside the .pkg file (notice how large it is?). You'll need to unpack it using something like [AnyToISO](http://www.crystalidea.com/extract-pkg-files-mac-and-windows).

Comment: i Am the one ask really nice. but never get the right answer.

Comment: @sukihinata What you just did wasn't very nice. He gave you a correct answer. The .app file is inside the .pkg file. Just extract it.